# Attempting to use a volume in my docker container (windows) and when I run docker run it does not appear to work

Tags: windows, bash, docker, docker-volume

A simple bash script whereby a user can search through a folder and organise their files by type. For this I need to give my container access to my C drive and navigate to the right directory where the code is executed and where the folders are.

Since it s windows I know I need to use winpty and use \ rather than / when navigating.

```
winpty docker run -it -v basic-vol:/C:\Users\XYZ\dev\repos\filefind filefind:latest
```

I am not sure why this is not working. Here is my Dockerfile too:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN chmod 700 .
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
VOLUME [ "/c/Users/XYZ/dev/repos/"]
#when conatiner starts what is the executable
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "file-find.sh"]
```

Would love your help here folks